# How to print the value of data dynamically. The position of data can be up to nth level

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, object

**How to print the value of data dynamically. The position of data can be up to nth level.**

```
x = {
     a: {
        b: {
           c: {
              d: {
                  data: 'hello'
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a recursive function like the following way:

```js
const x = {
     a: {
        b: {
           c: {
              d: {
                  data: 'hello'
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
     
function getValue(obj){
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  for(var k of keys){
    if (typeof obj[keys] === 'object') {
      return getValue(obj[keys]);
    }
    else if(keys == 'data'){
      return obj[keys];
    }
    else{
      return 'not found';
    }
  }
}
console.log(getValue(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample recursive javascript function :

```
function find(obj,keyword){
 if(obj[keyword]){
  return obj[keyword];
 }
 for(key in obj){
  if(typeof obj[key] === 'object'){
    var result=find(obj[key],keyword);
    if(result){
      return result;
    }
  }
 }
 return false;
}
x = {
   a: {
      b: {
         c: {
            d: {
                data: 'hello'
               }
            }
         }
      }
   };
result = find(x,"data");
console.log(result);
```